# How can I update a nested field in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I defined a DynamoDB table and it has a nested field `site`. I'd like to update the field `site.enable` in below code. But when I run the update command I got this error:

> **ValidationException:** The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update`

What should I do in order to fix the issue?

```
{
      TableName: 'MyTable',
      Key: {
        id: '4b7020d2-2d19-4aeb-7f27e49d5bec',
        type: '80422149-c97d-4a1a-7bf20ef57056',
      },
      UpdateExpression: 'set #site.#siteenable= :siteenable',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':siteenable': true,
      },
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#siteenable': 'enable',
        '#site': 'site',
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given code works fine if the map `site` exists already, seeing the error message, it looks like the path `site` doesn't exist.

We could create empty map during the create of the document, then update it easily OR
We could create the map during the update `"set #site = :siteValue"`

Here is slightly modified query which creates the map.

```
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

docClient.update(
  {
    TableName: "MyTable",
    Key: {
      id: "4b7020d2-2d19-4aeb-7f27e49d5bec",
      type: "80422149-c97d-4a1a-7bf20ef57056",
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set #site = :siteValue",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":siteValue": { enable: true },
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#site": "site",
    },
  },
  function (error, result) {
    console.log("error", error, "result", result);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think you are right that the site doesn't exist. Your solution works to create a site if it doesn't exist. But if the site already exists and it has fields other than `enable`, it will override the other fields. That's why I am looking for a update works for both creating and updating.

Comment: One certainly is to create an empty map when inserting a new record, then your code is enough. Or we can completely skip update if map already exists using if_not_exists. if we want to do both during the update, i can only think of doing in two queries.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention a programming language, so I'm going to assume what I'm used to: Python.

In Python there are two ways you can do this:

1. The lower level client API, which requires you to format the data the way DynamoDB would

```py
def enable_site_with_client():

    ddb = boto3.client("dynamodb")
    ddb.update_item(
        TableName=TABLE_NAME,
        Key={
            "PK": {"S": "SITE_ENTRY"}
        },
        UpdateExpression="SET #site.#enabled = :update_value",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            "#site": "site",
            "#enabled": "enabled"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":update_value": {"BOOL": True}
        }
    )
```

2. The higher level resource API, which allows you to use the language native data structures

```py
def enable_site_with_resource():

    ddb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    ddb.Table(TABLE_NAME).update_item(
        Key={
            "PK": "SITE_ENTRY"
        },
        UpdateExpression="SET #site.#enabled = :update_value",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            "#site": "site",
            "#enabled": "enabled"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":update_value": True
        }
    )
```

I have tested both of these and they work.

Comment: The update method allows updating existing items and creating new items.  With the code you have presented here, it will result in an exception when creating a new item, because the "site" level attribute was not previously present.  I have found examples that first make an api call to see if the property exists and then makes a second api call to save in a way that accounts for the existence of the root property.  Is there a way to make a single api call that can account for both scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for Java SDK V2 that will update root->nested->someValue

```
        Map<String, AttributeValue> attributeValues = new HashMap<>();
        attributeValues.put(":myValue", AttributeValue.builder().s(jsonString).build());

        UpdateItemRequest updateRequest = UpdateItemRequest.builder()
                .tableName("my_table_name")
                .key(keyToUpdate)
                .updateExpression("SET nested.someValue= :myValue")
                .expressionAttributeValues(attributeValues)
                .build();

        client.updateItem(updateRequest);
```